# Need advice on storing pincode system (Zip code) and Shipping company Service Details

Tags: mariadb

I'm on the process of creating system that could identify shipping companies (Fedex,UPS etc...) from a given pincode (zip code) for e-commerce platform.

The shipping companies will provide a list of pincodes where they provide pickup and delivery. So when we get an order for a product, with the pincode of the seller and with pincode of buyer i need to get a list of shipping companies who provides both these services ie pickup and delivery.

My initial plan is to create a table structure like following one;

```
shipping_companies
-------------------
1. Fedex
2. UPS
3. DHL

pincodes
----------
id pincode | shipping_ids_pickup | shipping_ids_delivery
1. 263152           1,2                2,3
```

The pincodes table will have the pincodes and will have two columns one for pickup and another for delivery.

So when a user purchases a product i need to find a shipping company that has pickup from the sellers location and also has delivery at buyers location.

If we are adding another shipping company in the future i can update the  shipping_ids_pickup, shipping_ids_delivery for a pincode by appending the id.

Can someone suggest a better solution. Is there any issue with current approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any issue with current approach.

Yes.  You're storing multiple values in single columns:

```
pincodes
----------
id pincode | shipping_ids_pickup | shipping_ids_delivery
1. 263152           1,2                2,3

                     ^------ here ------^
```

This is going to make querying and maintaining the data ***much*** more difficult than it needs to be.  The code is going to be putting more focus on string manipulation than on matching customers to shipping companies.

The business need is to match customers with shipping companies.  The business need is not to manipulate string values.

Instead, store individual data elements as just that... individual data elements.  Start with the two entities that you have:

```
Shipping Companies
--------
ID (int, PK)
Name (string)

Pincodes
--------
ID (int, PK)
Pincode (string)
```

These entities have a many-to-many relationship.  So create a table to link them:

```
Shipping Company Pincodes
--------
ID (int, PK)
Shipping Company ID (int, FK)
Pincode ID (int, FK)
Pickup (bit)
Delivery (bit)
```

The relationship *itself* essentially becomes an entity in the domain.  Not necessarily a primary business entity (that is, not an aggregate root), but a logical entity all the same.  That entity is maintained separately from the aggregate roots to which it relates.

Querying and updating the data becomes *a lot* easier, and the code can focus on the semantics of the business logic being performed rather than all sorts of overhead of performing it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed reply... I do not have enough points to up vote you. I will do that once i have that. Thanks again for your time.