# Storing pincodes and shipping charge for each pincode

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm Creating a E-Commerce application using Magento. I need to build a custom Shipping module for this. Currently i'm designing the tables to store data.

The issue is when a customer places an order i need to get the Shipping companies who provides service in that locations ie Pickup and delivery. Once i have the details of the shipping company i need to get the shipping charge to that particular location. I have asked a question about how to store pincodes and shipping company [detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363921/need-advice-on-stroing-pincode-system-zip-code-and-shipping-company-service-de).

The suggestion i got was to create a table like as follows

```
    Shipping Companies
    --------
    ID (int, PK)
    Name (string)

    Pincodes
    --------
    ID (int, PK)
    Pincode (string)

    These entities have a many-to-many relationship.  So create a table to link them:

    Shipping Company Pincodes
    --------
    ID (int, PK)
    Shipping Company ID (int, FK)
    Pincode ID (int, FK)
    Pickup (bit)
    Delivery (bit)
```

Using this table structure i can track the shipping companies which will provide pickup and delivery . However once i have these shipping company ids, the next step i need to do is get the shipping charges to deliver the product at that location. One suggestion from one of my colleague was to store the range of pincodes instead of storing all the pincodes. And row will store the rate for multiple shipping company For example:

```
Pincode   |  Fedex Rate   |   DHL Rate  |  UPS Rate
----------------------------------------------------
67 - 69        7.7              6.5          5.5
```

But since i'm storing a range of pincodes how will i identify if shipping company does not provide delivery or pickup in any pincode in that range. Also is there any other better method to store the shipping rates for pincodes. There are actually around 19000+ pincodes. I thought of storing individual rates for each pincode and shipping company, but that will make the table very huge.

Comment: "does not provide" -- sounds like a good use for `NULL`.

Comment: Do you need a table of "from 'here' to anywhere"?  Or a table of "from _anywhere_ to _anywhere_"?

Comment: 19000 rows is "small", not "huge".  It it is properly indexed (`PRIMARY KEY(pin)`), the performance will be excellent.

Comment: I mean for a single shipping company there will be 19000 rows, like pincode_id shipping_company_id rate. There will at least 4 shipping companies.

Comment: Go with 19K rows.  More complex to load, but very fast to query.

Answer (score 1):

Tens of thousands of rows is small for MySQL/MariaDB.  I would forego the `Pincodes` table as well as the surrogate `ID` in the `Shipping Company Pincodes` table and use the `Shipping Company ID` and `Pincode` as a composite primary key.  The `Pincode` looks like an integer (no less efficient than a surrogate id) and a meaningful natural (externally defined) key, meaning you'll likely need it frequently in queries.  If it forms part of your primary keys, it'll be conveniently available and indexed by default.  I would also add a `Rate` column to this table.

To summarize:

```
Shipping Companies
--------
ID (int, PK)
Name (string)

Shipping Company Pincodes 
--------
Shipping Company ID (int, PK/FK)
Pincode (int, PK/FK)
Pickup (bit)
Delivery (bit)
Rate (decimal)
```

Comment: But, doesn't the desired table need 19000*19000/2 rows?

Comment: Rather than record all combinations of pincodes, perhaps one can join this table to itself to derive the same info.

Comment: But isn't the price dependent on both the source pin and the dest pin?

Comment: I didn't see anything like that in the original question.

Comment: So we need to create a mapping for each shipping company and pincode right? So if there are multiple shipping companies there will be multiple entries for a pincode. For example if shipping company A and B both provides service on pincode 685608 then there will be two entries.. will that be a problem? I need to find all the shipping company that have delivery on 685608 and find the least price

Comment: Yes, a row for every shipping company and pincode, you'll be able to query for the company who delivers for the lowest rate.  Will you need different rates for pickup and delivery?

Comment: With an open-ended number of carriers, it would be better to a bigger table that has 4 columns: target_pin, carrier_id, deliver_cost, receive_cost. The PK would be on first 2 columns. 3*160K rows is still not very big.  (Since not all carriers go to all pins, it would be smaller than 3*160K.)

Comment: The `SELECT` would be `... ORDER BY delivery_price DESC LIMIT 1`.  Still very efficient.

Comment: I'm thinking of splitting it into `pickup_rates (carrier_id PK/FK, pincode PK, rate)` and `delivery_rates (carrier_id PK/FK, pincode PK, rate)` if rates can differ, basically a normalized version of what you're suggesting.

Comment: A minor issue:  Splitting into 2 tables (vs 1 table with 2 rates) will take nearly twice the disk space.

Comment: 100K rows in your table in InnoDB takes 4.52MB, 100K rows in my two tables take 7.04MB, not counting overhead like reserved free space.  The storage space costs less than the time you took to type your comment, and there are other factors to consider besides absolute size, like how many rows fit into a page and the consequences of nulls.

Answer (score 1):

*This addresses a more complex question, so it is not really addressing the one asked.*

Is the main query is "What will the companies charge to ship from Pin 12345 to Pin 29876?"

**Plan A** is a 360 million row table with all possible start/end pins.  This may be the best, since it is very efficient to do `SELECT ... WHERE pin_from = $from AND pin_to = $to` while having `PRIMARY KEY(pin_from, pin_to)`.  This table might take 20GB; is that OK?  The `SELECT` might typically take 10ms.

**Plan B**, which you alluded to, would need a table like

```
CREATE TABLE Rates (
    from_a, from_z,   -- min and max pins for source pin range
    to_a, to_z,       -- ditto for destination
    fedex DECIMAL(6,2) NULL   -- NULLable in case fedex does not run that route
    etc.
    PRIMARY KEY(from_a, from_z, to_a, to_z)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The table would be much smaller.  The query is something like:

```
SELECT  IFNULL(fedex, 'N/A')  AS Fedex, ...
    FROM Rates
    WHERE $from BETWEEN from_a AND from_z
      AND $to   BETWEEN to_a   AND to_z;
```

The problem is that there is no good way to index this.  This encounters two problems -- testing within a range in that way is not optimizable, and it is essentially a 2-dimensional problem.

If the table is only thousands of rows, then a table scan is not "too bad".  If it is millions of rows, it would probably be too slow.

Loading the table would be a lot of challenging code -- you don't want any overlapping rectangles.  Updating the table would be even more challenging.

**Plan C**...  Perhaps a `SPATIAL` index is exactly what you need.  The (x,y) of a Spatial "Point" is the pair (pin_from, pin_to).  Sorry, I don't know where to take it next.

**Plan D**...  This is a variant on Plan B, but it greatly improves the efficiency.  It adds 2 columns;  x, y.  They have values 0..190, calculated as floor(pin/100).  The idea is to have 190*190 "buckets".  In each bucket is every rectangle (a la Plan B) that has a point in the bucket.  Yes, that means some rectangles will show up in more than one bucket; this is a small price to pay for significant performance improvement.

```
PRIMARY KEY(x, y, from_a, from_z, to_a, to_z)

SELECT ...
    FROM Rates
    WHERE x = FLOOR($from/100)
      AND y = FLOOR($to/100)
      AND the rest of Plan B's WHERE
```

Since a "bucket" cannot have more than 100*100 rows, and they are "clustered" in the table, the scan is reasonably bounded.  If, say, the average bucket is 10 pins by 10 pins, then the average bucket has only 100 rows -- quite efficient.

Sorry, loading and updating is still complex.

(I picked 100x100 for bucket size; there may be a better choice, based on the size of the typical rectangle.  Note the advantage of 100:  it leads to 0..190 range, allowing x and y to be small: a 1-byte `TINYINT UNSIGNED`.)

Comment: Thank you very much for a such a detailed answer. Yes I'm looking to find out what will be the charge to ship from pincode 123 to pincode 4566. I will have to store the charges of multiple carriers like Fedex, UPS etc.. I think that there will be at least 4 carriers. But Currently i'm only using data from the Fedex. In the future i will have to integrate other carriers also. There are around 1,60,000 pincodes. And among them fedex is serving around 19,000 locations. Some of them only have delivery.

Comment: Need an advice on the Plan A. Instead of keeping all the possible combination how about keeping a range combination? For example consider the pincodes 676303,676387,67642 and 695382,695381,695650. For the pincode 676303 there are 6 possible combinations. But if take first three numbers of the pincode ie 676 - 676 and 676 - 695 there are only 2 combination and keep rate for only these two combination

Comment: The problem is that looking up with `BETWEEN` cannot be optimized well.